# Kali Linux image for Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, kali

I wanted to install Kali Linux for my Pi 3.

I have a class 10 64 GB SD card.

I am new to Raspberry Pi 3.

Please tell me which image should I choose.

Answer (score 7):

You download the image for Kali from [this page](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/).

You then extract the file on your PC and burn the image onto the SD card using something like Win32DiskImager.

Plug the SD card into your Pi2/Pi3 with a USB keyboard. It should boot up into a login GUI prompt will show up.

> Default Username/Passwords: root/toor

*The first thing I would do is regenerate your SSH keys and change root password. Now a days it is not really good practice to release images with default passwords and SSH host keys. User should be setting root password and generating keys on their hardware on first boot.*